# Tough Recurrence Relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm trying to find a recurrence equation solution to
$$f(n)=a(n)f(n-1)+f(n-2)$$
with the initial conditions that $f(-1)=0, f(-2)=1$ and $$a(n)=\frac{c}{2}(1+(-1)^n)-\frac{d}{n+1}(1-(-1)^n)$$ with some constants $c$ and $d$.
 Alternatively we could write $a(2n)=c$ and $a(2n-1)=-\frac{d}{n}$ and try to solve the cases seperately.

Comment: consider rewriting $\cos(\pi(n+1))=(-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: alternatively, consider writing separate cases for $n$ even and odd (e.g. $f(2k)$ and $f(2k+1)$)

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b = cd$ and we will assume $b \ne 0$.

Let $f_n = f(n)$, the recurrence relation can be rewritten as

$$f_n - f_{n-2} = f_{n-1}\times 
\begin{cases}
c, & n \text{ even }\\
-\frac{2d}{n+1},& n\text{ odd }
\end{cases}
\quad\iff\quad
\begin{cases}
f_{2m} - f_{2m-2} &=  c f_{2m-1}\\
f_{2m+1} - f_{2m-1} &= -\frac{d f_{2m}}{m+1}
\end{cases}
$$
Let $g_m = f_{2m}$, it is clear once we figure out what $g_m$ are, we can compute $f_{2m-1}$ from $g_m$ and $g_{m-1}$.
It is clear $g_{-1} = g_0 = 1$. Furthermore, for any $m \ge 0$, we have

$$g_{m+1} - 2 g_m + g_{m-1} = (f_{2m+2}-f_{2m}) - (f_{2m} - f_{2m-2}) = c(f_{2m+1} - f_{2m-1}) = -\frac{b g_m}{m+1}$$

Let $g(z) = \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty g_m z^m$ be the OGF. Multiply both sides of above equation by $z^{m+1}$ and start to sum from $m = 0$, we get

$$(g(z)-1) - 2zg(z) + (z + z^2g(z)) = 
(1-z)^2 g(z) + (z-1) = -b\int_0^z g(t)dt
$$
Differentiate $z$ on both sides, we get
$$\begin{align}
& (1-z)^2 g'(z) - 2(1-z) g(z) + 1 = - b g(z)\\
\iff & g'(z) + \left[ -\frac{2}{1-z} + \frac{b}{(1-z)^2}\right] g = - \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}\\
\iff & \frac{d}{dz}\left[ (1-z)^2 e^{bz/(1-z)} g(z) \right] = - e^{bz/(1-z)}\\
\implies & g(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}e^{-bz/(1-z)}\left[ 1 - \int_0^z e^{bt/(1-t)} dt \right]\tag{*1}
\end{align}
$$
With some algebra, we can express $g(z)$ in terms of 
[exponential integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).
$$\frac{1}{1-z} - \frac{b}{(1-z)^2} e^{-b/(1-z)}\left[{\mathrm Ei}\left(\frac{b}{1-z}\right) - {\mathrm Ei}(b)\right]$$
Unluckily, I cannot figure out how to use this to extract a nice expression
of $g_n$. It turns out there is another ugly way.

Recall the definition of [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) $L_n(x)$ in terms of its OGF:
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty t^m L_m(x) = \frac{1}{1-t} e^{-xt/(1-t)}$$
We find

$$1 - \int_0^z e^{bt/(1-t)}  dt
= 1 - \int_0^1 \sum_{m=0}^\infty t^m(1-t) L_m(-b) dt
= 1 - z - \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{L_m(-b) - L_{m-1}(b)}{m+1} z^{m+2}
$$
As a result,

$$g(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty L_n(b) z^n\right)\left((1-z) - z^2 \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{L_m(-b) - L_{m-1}(b)}{m+1} z^m \right)$$

Compare coefficients of both sides, we find $g_n$ is a polynomial in $b$ of degree $n$.

$$f_{2n} = g_n = L_n(b) - \underbrace{\sum_{q=0}^{n-2}\frac{L_{q+1}(-b)-L_{q}(-b)}{q+2}\left(\sum_{p=0}^{n-2-q} L_p(b)\right)}_{= 0 \text{ when } n < 2}$$

Using this formula, the first few $g_{n}$ are given below
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
g_0 &=& 1\\
g_1 &=& 1-b\\
2!g_2 &=& 2-5b+b^2\\
3!g_3 &=& 6-26b+11b^2-b^3\\
4!g_4 &=& 24-154b+102b^2-19b^3+b^4\\
5!g_5 &=& 120-1044b+954b^2-272b^3+29b^4-b^5
\end{array}
$$
They match what one get if we solve the recurrence relations by brute force.